# Excel VBA and Selenium. How can i check if a certain Text is present in the page?

Tags: excel, selenium, vba

I'm automating a webpage using Excel VBA and Selenium. In a certain page how can i check if a certain Text is present in the page?

Comment: if possible can you provide some more details

Answer (score 0):

You can try to locate the element with an XPath:

```
Dim drv As New FirefoxDriver
drv.Get "https://www.google.co.uk"

If drv.FindElementsByXPath("//*[contains(text(),'Google')]").Count Then
  Debug.Print "Text is present"
Else
  Debug.Print "Text is not present"
End If

drv.Quit
```

Or by directly checking the content:

```
Const JS_HAS_TEXT = "return document.body.textContent.indexOf(arguments[0]) > -1"

Dim drv As New FirefoxDriver
drv.Get "https://www.google.co.uk"

If drv.ExecuteScript(JS_HAS_TEXT, "Google") Then
  Debug.Print "Text is present"
Else
  Debug.Print "Text is not present"
End If
```